# count how many times return true .include? ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a function I am building where I need to check if the value from a hash object includes a specific word/string.

I can get my `|key, value|` value to return if all the values include the specific phrase giving me a list of true or false and I just need the output the number of `true`s.

```
def example(array)
  array.each do |company|
    company.each do |key, value|
      val_count = value["email_hosts"].include?("gmail")
      puts gmail_count
    end
  end
end

example(request)
```

this outputs:

```
false
false
true
true
false
true
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

I need the output to just be 3, for the three `true`s.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using [select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)?

Comment: You have a `val_count` variable that you never use, you're assigning it to the result of `.include?` which will be a boolean so it's confusing that the name is `val_count` which implies a number, you have never declared the `gmail_count` variable though you're `puts`ing it. Also you're showing the output but not the input so people trying to help you just have to guess?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using [`count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-select) to count the entries which match in each company and then [`sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-sum) them together.

```
companies = [
  { this: { "email_hosts" => "hotestmail" } },
  {
    this: { "email_hosts" => "gmail" },
    that: { "email_hosts" => "gmail.com" },
    other: { "email_hosts" => "gmail.com" }
  }
]

puts companies.sum { |company|
  company.count { |_,host|
    host["email_hosts"].include?("gmail")
  }
}
```

Comment: Enumerable#count accepts a block. Better than a select/size combo.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks. There's always more Ruby convenience methods to learn.